# Display primary key Sonata Admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I am using Sonata Admin Bundle and Sumfony 2.3.3. I have a Product table and a Brand table. The brand id is put in product table. Now when I display the product table, I need to display the Brand name instead of the brand id, and that should come from the brand table. How can i do this? Please help me. Thanks

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('product_id')
        ->add('product_name')
        ->add('brand_id')
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can work : `$listMapper->add('brand.name');`